# PercentRelativeLayout - layout_width missing warning

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm trying out PercentRelativeLayout from the support library, and [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) just ask me to specify an app:layout_widthPercent property. However, when I do that, Android Studio gives me a red warn saying that the layout_width is unspecified.

Other than suppressing the warning, is there a way around this?

For example:

```
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/expiry_month_wrapper"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/expiry_month_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="2"
                android:hint="@string/month"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:inputType="number"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

      <!-- more TextInputLayout fields -->

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Warning given on TextInputLayout.

Comment: I have same issue. Does it result in something bad or just warning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is an old question - but having just encountered this problem I want to make sure it's available for everyone :)

Adding a view to your `PercentRelativeLayout` will throw a visual error in the text editor. It may fail to render on the screen even. Go ahead and run your emulator and it should resolve the visibility issue.

To resolve the error just add `android:layout_width="0dp"` So long as your `widthPercent` and `heightPercent` are set appropriately you'll not have an issue.

Here's my example of tested code

```
            android:text="Label label"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Other other other"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
            app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

By convention, both layout_width and layout_height need to be included even when they're functionally ignored by PercentRelativeLayout's app:layout_widthPercent and app:layout_aspectRatio, respectively.

In your case, by solely using app:layout_widthPercent, just set android:layout_width to any number of density-independent pixels to get rid of the warning.

For instance:
android:layout_width = "0dp"

Comment: But be careful... we know that "wrap_content", for instance, has a very specific meaning with PercentRelativeLayout... the fields aren't ignored completely.