# Android PercentRelativeLayout width and height should be specified

Tags: android, android-percentrelativelayout, android-percent-library

I'm trying to use `android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout`:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
                app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
                app:layout_aspectRatio="1000%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="15%"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Android Studio gives me errors:**

```
"layout_height should be specified
"layout_width should be specified"

Project is building now, but studio shows errors and do not suggest autocompletion when I start typing "percent..."
```

What am I doing wrong?

[Here is](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) example from official site, why it's not working?

Comment: make it `0dp` for `"layout_height` and `"layout_widht`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was answered here : [PercentRelativeLayout - layout_width missing warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682512/percentrelativelayout-layout-width-missing-warning)

Basically; width and height are ignored by PercentRelativeLayout, but you need to set them to 0dp, because Android Studio expects them to be here.